# How to unset a protocol buffer field?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

How would you unset a protocol buffer variable.

Given this `.proto`:

```
message Product {
    optional float price = 5;
}
```

If one tries deleting the item:

```
del product.price
```

this results:

```
AttributeError: can't delete attribute
```

If one tries setting the variable to `None`:

```
product.price = None
```

this results:

```
TypeError: Cannot set mypackage.Product.price_was to None: None has type <class 'NoneType'>, but expected one of: numbers.Real
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ClearField` like

```
product.ClearField('price')
```

[Full docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fields)